# Angular finding time difference in days between two dates but one date format is laravel carbon

Tags: angular, laravel

Hello i want to find the difference between these 2 dates. So as i understand, this is the code for angular getting current date.

```
let currentDate = new Date();
```

and in the console log, the format is this. Fri Sep 03 2021 10:49:33 GMT+0800 but the other date that i retrieved from the database is in laravel carbon format i think which is like 2021-08-13T07:17:57.000000Z. Is there a way to find the difference between these 2 dates?

Comment: `new Date("2021-08-13T07:17:57.000000Z")` will still work... you will have access to the laravel date in js.

Comment: oh man thanks! you're a lifesaver

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick with dates you can refer [Get difference between 2 dates in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224834/get-difference-between-2-dates-in-javascript) or use [moment js](https://momentjs.com/) like this:

```
const today = moment();
const someday = moment('Fri Sep 03 2021 10:49:33 GMT+0800');

const diffDays = today.diff(someday, 'day');
const diffMin = today.diff(someday, 'minute');
const diffSec = today.diff(someday, 'second');
```

But be aware that moment js adds a bit of an overhead to your application. Only use it if you have significant amount of date/time related calculations.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but the  user3532758 comment was what i needed.

Comment: from Moment.js website:
`Considering using Moment in your project?
There may be better modern alternatives.
For more details and recommendations,
please see Project Status in the docs.`

You may consider other libraries such as luxon